# dir path puzzle in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, path, find

What's the differences between `/home/zzz` and `/home/zzz/` when used in bash?

I just found that when `/home/zzz` is a link to another dir, `find /home/zzz -type f` will get nothing, but `find /home/zzz/ -type f` will return all files under that dir. I think bash treat `/home/zzz` a link type file, but `/home/zzz/` a dir in this case.

Is there any other differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trailing slash is interpreted by most Unix utilities (`find` in this case) to mean "follow the symlink".

From the [POSIX Symbolic Link Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap03.html#tag_21_03_00_59):

> When the final component of a pathname is a symbolic link, the
>   standard requires that a trailing slash causes the link to be
>   followed. This is the behavior of historical implementations. For
>   example, for **/a/b** and **/a/b/**, if **/a/b** is a symbolic link to a
>   directory, then **/a/b** refers to the symbolic link, and **/a/b/** refers to
>   the directory to which the symbolic link points.

Also see [GNU Coreutils: Trailing slashes](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Trailing-slashes.html).

Comment: What if `/home/zzz` a dir instead of link? Is there any differences?

Answer (score 1):

Its not bash, Its **find** who treats a symbolic link as a symbolic link and reads the property from itself, Not reading property from the file it points to. See what [find(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) says,

> Never follow symbolic links. **This is the default behaviour**. When find examines or prints information a file, and the file is a symbolic link, **the information used shall be taken from the properties of the symbolic link itself**.

To treat it as a directory you need to use `-L` option.

> When the -L option is in effect, the -type predicate will always match against the type of the file that a symbolic link points to rather than the link itself (unless the symbolic link is broken). Using -L causes the -lname and -ilname predicates always to return false.

My guess is when you pass a trailing slash `/` bash tries to resolve it and find sees it as a directory. If you are sure that there is no recursive symbolic links in a directory tree you can call `find` with `-L` option.  So following command should work.

```
find -L /home/zzz -type f
```

Comment: `find` is not the only cmd treat them that way, but also `ls`, so i think there must be some common rule, that common rule is what i want to know.